# Get a single product for each category in laravel

Tags: mysql, laravel, database, eloquent, relationship

I have two tables one is products and the other is categories with a one to many relationship

categories:

| id | name |
| --- | --- |
| - | - |
| - | - |

products:

| id | name | price |
| --- | --- | --- |
| First | row | - |
| Second | row | - |

I already made the pivot table and the relation in code in Laravel.
but what I'm trying to achieve is that for each category there is only one product and also that every time a new product is added it is placed first with the category.

I managed to make there be only one product per category with this code:

```
    Category::with('products')->orderBy('id', 'desc')->get()->map(function($categories) {
    $categories->setRelation('products', $categories->products->sortByDesc('id')->take(1));
    return $categories;
});
```

this solves the problem of a recent product by category but it does not solve the problem that when adding a new product in a category it is put first in the array

the query returns this where the last product I added was the coconut

```
 [
  {
    "id": 1,
    "name": "dairy",
    "products": {
      "6": {
        "id": 4,
        "name": "yoghurt",
        "price": "1",
        "created_at": "2022-09-02T16:45:24.000000Z",
        "updated_at": "2022-09-02T16:45:24.000000Z",
        "pivot": {
          "category_id": 1,
          "product_id": 4
        }
      }
    }
  },
  {
    "id": 2,
    "name": "fruits",
    "products": [
      {
        "id": 10,
        "name": coconut",
        "price": "2",
        "created_at": "2022-09-02T11:28:12.000000Z",
        "updated_at": "2022-08-15T00:24:00.000000Z",
        "pivot": {
          "category_id": 2,
          "product_id": 10
        }
      }
    ]
  }
]
```

This would be what I want to get:

where when adding a new product it is positioned in the first place with the category

```
    [
{
            "id": 2,
            "name": "fruits",
            "products": [
              {
                "id": 10,
                "name": coconut",
                "price": "2",
                "created_at": "2022-09-02T11:28:12.000000Z",
                "updated_at": "2022-08-15T00:24:00.000000Z",
                "pivot": {
                  "category_id": 2,
                  "product_id": 10
                }
              }
            ]
          },
          {
            "id": 1,
            "name": "dairy",
            "products": {
              "6": {
                "id": 4,
                "name": "yoghurt",
                "price": "1",
                "created_at": "2022-09-02T16:45:24.000000Z",
                "updated_at": "2022-09-02T16:45:24.000000Z",
                "pivot": {
                  "category_id": 1,
                  "product_id": 4
                }
              }
            }
          }
]
```

Thanks for reading and I appreciate the help.

Answer (score 1):

There are multiple ways you can do this. One of them would be to use the new “[one of many](https://laravel.com/docs/9.x/eloquent-relationships#has-one-of-many)” relationship.

```php
class Category extends Model
{
    public function latest_product()
    {
        return $this->hasOne(Login::class)->latestOfMany();
    }
}
```

Then you can do something like:

```php
Category::with('latest_product')->latest('id')->get();
```

Also, since you have a pivot table, it should be a many-to-many relationship. If it is supposed to be a one-to-many, the `category_id` should be in the `products` table; not a pivot table.

**Edit:**

If you want the results to be ordered by the `product_id` instead of the `category_id`, something like this should work:

With Collection:

```php
Category::with('latest_product')
    ->get()
    ->sortByDesc(fn ($query) => $query->latest_product->id);
```

With Subquery:

```php
Category::with('latest_product')
    ->orderByDesc(
        DB::table('category_product')
            ->select('product_id')
            ->whereColumn('category_product.category_id', 'categories.id'))
            ->latest('product_id')
            ->take(1)
    ->get()
```

The second approach is probably faster. But I didn't test either of these. So might need some adjustments :)

Comment: the relationship I have is one to many, since a category can have many products, but a product can only have one category. what I am looking for is that all the products added in a category only show the last one recently added and that at the same time when a new product is added to the database it changes its order and is positioned at the top of the list with the category

Comment: That is why I put the example of the coconut where, being the last product added in the entire database, it should be the first with its category, but the query that I make only shows me in the order of the category table, not in the order of the products

Comment: I meant there is an inconsistency between how you have structured your database vs how you have defined your relations. Anyway, I have updated my answer which should work despite the relationships.